# Powershell: Pulling from a list (CSV) running a command and outputting to a different CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting

very new to heavier powershell and I've been hacking at this all day and can't figure it out.

I need to get a list of UPNs from office 365 accounts.  I have the names in a CSV file.  It has one column, with a long list of names.  Heading is "name"

I want to run the get-user command against every name with the pipe format-list name, universalprincipalname and then output it to a new file.

I tried this:

```
get-content "m:\filename.csv" | 
foreach {get-user '$_.user' -identity -resultsize unlimited} |
format-list name, userprincipalname |
out-file -FilePath m:\newfilename.csv
```

But it did not work (I also tried it with import-csv).  It seemed to instead of pulling from my list, pull right from the office365 exchange server and when it finally finished had way more names in it than I have in my list.

My overall goal is to generate a list of upns of all the people who *do not* have mobile devices with their account so I can use a powershell command to disable active sync and OWA for mobile devices.  Unfortunately, the command I used to generate my list of users produced the list in first name, last name format...and we have so many users I can't just concatenate the thing in excel, because there would be a ton of mistakes.

CSV is laid out like this:

```
Column1  
name   
first last  
first last  
first last  
first last
```

Comment: If the header is named "name" you have to use `$_.name` as your pipeline variable.

Comment: ... AND ... if you want to create a proper CSV file you should use `Export-Csv` instead of `Out-File` ;-)

Comment: Don't you mean to use `Import-Csv` instead of `Get-Content`?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart  ... ooops ... I even missed that ...

Comment: Do you mean `Get-ADUser`?

Comment: No, get-aduser for whatever reason won't resolve upn, even though it should...I don't get it

Comment: @olaf and Bill - when I try it with $_name. I get a "get-user missing an argument for parameter 'Identity' for every name in the list.

Comment: Your CSV actually has `Column1` or `name` as header? its not quite clear.

Comment: No, cell a1 is Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the CSV's header is `Name`, the code should look like this:

```
Import-Csv "m:\filename.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    Get-User -Identity $_.Name.Trim() -ResultSize Unlimited
} | Select-Object Name, UserPrincipalName |
Export-Csv "m:\newfilename.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Note that I'm using `Select-Object` instead of `Format-Table`. You should only use `Format-Table` to display your output to the PowerShell host, objects passed through the pipeline to this cmdlet will be recreated into a new object of the type `FormatEntryData` which you **do not** want if your intent is to export the data.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the issue, but I'm not sure why this is happening.  It's not working because it appears to be inserting a single ' at the beginning of each cell and another one after adding about 20 spaces to the end of each name.  Perhaps I should copy and paste into a text file and abandon CSV?

Comment: Also - if I do this manually, omitting the import csv and the export, and skipping the section "foreach-object" this works exactly how I want it to.  So the problem appears to be either in the part between the {}s or in the csv / txt files themselves.

Comment: @Den026 assuming you have a valid CSV my code should work perfectly fine. Try importing your CSV and see how it looks.

Comment: you are right.  I just copied the csv to a text file and there are extra spaces after each name.  It's what is killing this whole thing as when I ran a test in a text file I created manually it worked exactly how you stated!  I will re-generate my list and see if I am actually correct (but in experimentation it did work!)

Comment: @Den026 see that I added `.Trim()` on my code. That should remove the trailing and leading whitespaces as long as the `Name` header doesn't have whitespaces too.

Comment: Squarezon - your code worked perfectly.  Thank you kindly!

Comment: @Den026 happy to help!